# Jquery :contains should ignore whitespace

Tags: jquery, contains, space

here is my code that works very fine. Found it on a website and modified a little bit.

```
<script>
(function ($) {
// custom css expression for a case-insensitive contains()
jQuery.expr[':'].Contains = function(a,i,m){
return (a.textContent || a.innerText || "").toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase())>=0;
};
function listFilter(header, list) { // header is any element, list is an unordered list
// create and add the filter form to the header
var form = $("<form>").attr({"class":"filterform","action":"#"}),
input = $("<input>").attr({"class":"filterinput","type":"text", "value":"Filterfunktion"});
$(form).append(input).appendTo(header);
$(input)
.change( function () {
var filter = $(this).val();


if(filter) {
// this finds all links in a list that contain the input,
// and hide the ones not containing the input while showing the ones that do
$(list).find("a:not(:Contains(" + filter + "))").parent().fadeOut();
$(list).find("a:Contains(" + filter + ")").parent().fadeIn();
} else {
$(list).find("li").slideDown();
}
return false;
})
.keyup( function () {
// fire the above change event after every letter
$(this).change();
});
}
//ondomready
$(function () {
listFilter($(".filter"), $(".list"));
});

$(function() {
    $(".filterinput").focus(function() {
      $(this).val('')

      });
 });

}(jQuery));
</script>
```

But the one thing that I cant get to work, is that the script should find/match a string when its with a whitespace and i type ist without a whitespace.

For exmpale:

I have < li>DCB 112. When I now type "DCB 112" in my inputfield it filter that correctly and show me that. But when I type "DCB112" the script cant match this and show me nothing. Is there a solution possible?

Greetings from Poland!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, maybe a bit twisted, but what I would do is taking all the links of the list and iterate over them, removing every whitespace of its text, and checking if the text you are looking for is in it. Something like this:

```
var filter = $(this).val().replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();

// I'm omitting loads of code...
var text;
var index;
$(list).find('a').each(function(i, el){
    text = $(el).text().replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
    index = text.indexOf(filter);
    if(index != -1){
        // The substring is contained -> show parent
    }else{
        // The substring is not contained -> hide parent
    }
});
```

Hope it helps and it works, as I didn't tested it :/

EDIT:

Tested and working :)

http://jsfiddle.net/QVkuP/

Comment: Very nice. Now I TRY to implement your code into my code, cause I am new @ jquery/javascript ;)

Comment: Now i got it. BUT it only works when I/the script care of CAPS and LOWER CASE. How can I fixed that?
< li>ABC 125</li> so only ABC125 works and abc125 doesn't work.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your code in jsfiddle? I can help you to adapt my code to work with yours

Comment: With the method toLowerCase() you can make it case insensitive (look at the answer edits)

Comment: here are my complete code that only works with care of CAPS and LOWE CASE: http://jsfiddle.net/QVkuP/20/

Comment: ok, I updated your code, including the latest edits of the answer: http://jsfiddle.net/QVkuP/23/

Comment: Strange, I tryed it the same way but with your code it works. Anyway you help me a LOT! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The easy way :

```
filter.replace(/\s/g, '');
```

But it will work well only if you have one whitespace, like "DCB 112".

The hard way :
You will need to loop first through your list to remove the links that do not match.
Careful to remove whitespaces from both values to compare.
And show the good ones.

```
$(list).find("a").each(function()
{
    if($(this).text().replace(/\s/g, '') == filter.replace(/\s/g, ''))
    {
        $(this).parent().fadeIn();
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).parent().fadeOut();
    }
}
```

Hope it will help, it still looks kind of ugly coding but it should do it...